# Batch: Assigning variable name of file that is originally pointed as wildcard

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wildcard

I have a script that compiles source maps, but the only way I can do this is to make a copy of the map(.vmf) file and name it mapCompiler_copy. I need to do this since the programs used to compile maps must have a specific name when identifying the map file.

Let's say I only have one .vmf file inside of a folder, lets say it is:

```
C:\CompilerScript\myMap.vmf
```

How would I use a batch script to assign the name "myMap" to a variable without originally knowing the name of the mapfile?(since different people would have their maps named differently).

```
set mapfolder=%1
set mapname=mapCompiler_copy.vmf
set mapname_bsp=mapCompiler_copy
copy /B %1\*.vmf %1\%mapname%
set map="%mapfolder%\%mapname%"
```

This is how the script works now, in which you drag and drop a folder onto the script, and the script makes a copy of the map file and names it mapCompiler_copy.vmf, which  I use later in the program, for example:

```
call vbsp.exe -notjunc -leaktest -game "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Source\cstrike" %map%
```

Edit: To be more specific, I will drag and drop a folder into the script, and the only contents of this folder is the map file (.vmf). I want the script to be able to store the name of the map with the only information being that the extension is (.vmf), and there is only one map file inside of the folder. This is because different people compiling multiple maps would have different names for their map files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FEXT=.vmf"
set "_NEXT=.bsp"

rem // Check (path) argument whether it exists:
if not exist "%~1" (>&2 echo ERROR: file not found!) & exit /B 1
rem // Check for directory or for file type (extension):
set "ATTR=%~a1"
if "%ATTR:~,1%"=="d" (
    rem // Argument is a directory, so get first matching file:
    set "FILE=" & set "NAME="
    for %%F in ("%~1\*%_FEXT%") do if not defined FILE (
        set "FILE=%%~fF" & set "NAME=%%~nxF"
        set "FNEW=%%~dpnF%_NEXT%" & set "NNEW=%%~nF%_NEXT%"
    )
) else if /I "%~x1"=="%_FEXT%" (
    rem // Argument is a file, so check its type (extension):
    set "FILE=%~f1" & set "NAME=%~nx1"
    set "FNEW=%~dpn1%_NEXT%" & set "NNEW=%~n1%_NEXT%"
)
rem // Check if a matching file has been found:
if not defined FILE (>&2 echo ERROR: file not found!) & exit /B 1

rem // Return found file:
echo or. path: "%FILE%"
echo or. name: "%NAME%"
echo new path: "%FNEW%"
echo new name: "%NNEW%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

So if a file is dragged-and-dropped onto the batch script, its extension (type) is checked against `.vmf`, and if it matches, its path and name are returned.
If a directory is dragged-and-dropped onto the batch script, its content (immediate file children) is checked and the path and name of the first found file with the `.vmf` extension are returned.

Comment: This solution works great, but is there any way I can also have the same map name assigned to a variable with .bsp at the end? This is for after the compilation, I need to copy it to the cstrike maps folder and also start the game with that map, but can only do so with the .bsp file not the .vmf file?

Comment: While this does work, whenever i use %FILE% for the compiling programs, it points to something else. Do I need to encapsulate the whole program and put the _endlocal_ at the end?

Comment: Also is there a way I can substring the mapname to just get the name without the extension. When passing a command to the game's console, the game knows it is a .bsp and that it is already in the respective maps folder, so you can only pass the mapname without the ".bsp" and the end.

Comment: The variables are lost beyond `endlocal`, so either insert the compiler program call before `endlocal`, or remove the initial `setlocal` and the `endlocal`...

Comment: Just change `set "_NEXT=.bsp"` to `set "_NEXT="`, so the `.bsp` extension is no longer appended...

Answer (score 0):

I think the following might help you. My assumption is that file extension is always of length 3 (and one period)

```
@echo off
Set fullpath=C:\CompilerScript\myMap.vmf
For %%A in ("%fullpath%") do (
    Set Name=%%~nxA
)
echo %Name:~0,-4%
```

Comment: `Set "Name=%%~nA"` without any pre-requisite.

Comment: Would this work if I did not know the name of the file, but I did know the extension. For example, if the mapnane was rp_downtown_complex. vmf, would I need to specify that?

Comment: The proposed answer should extract any length file name, as long as the file extension is 3 char long. You may test this and confirm it to yourself.